# Why does R have a different definition on convolution?

Tags: r, python, convolution, history

I found convolution in R works differently from Python. In Python, it will flip the input and run the convolution.

In the R documentation, it says

> Note that the **usual** definition of convolution of two sequences x and y is given by convolve(x, rev(y), type = "o").

Is there any reason behind R's different approach? Do people in the statistics community use convolution differently than do those in the signal processing community?

An example in R:

```
x = c(c(1,2,3,4),rep(0,4))
y = c(c(5,6,7,8),rep(0,4))
convolve(x,y) 

# will return 70 56 39 20  0  8 23 44
```

But in python

```
x = np.hstack([np.array([1,2,3,4]), np.zeros(4)])
y = np.hstack([np.array([5,6,7,8]), np.zeros(4)])

np.convolve(x, y)

# will return 5., 16., 34., 60., 61., 52., 32.
```

Comment: It is a design decision of the authors of the code. The "why" question is about their motivation, what's subjective.

Comment: I haven't check the details of the functions, but it is likely due to the implementation basing on cross correlation or convolution. I know that it could be different in deep learning frameworks.

Comment: @Tim I do not agree. there are many "facts" behind the decision. I am asking those facts.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question. This question is not opinion based like explaining which is better. It does to me more like a question about *how/why* these differences occur. Why are there multiple views on convolution, why is there a difference?

Comment: Apperently R's implementation of convolution is unusual. The documentation says: > Note that the usual definition of convolution of two sequences `x`and `y` is given by `convolve(x, rev(y), type = "o")`.

Comment: I would vote to open as well. This is fact, not opinion. The awareness of difference in different implementation would be helpful. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447270/pytorch-forward-pass-using-weights-trained-by-theano

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I am padding zero, so open or circular are the same

Comment: I am just quoting the documentation.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus sorry haven't read it carefully, it did indicate it is "unusal"

Comment: Of course this question will just be a matter about simple freedom in definitions/conventions and convolution allows two definitions. But it may be interesting to see why and where the unusual definition (by that I mean the definition used by R) pops up.

Comment: I'd say it's a convention, so as many "why" questions, something subjective, but would not oppose keeping it if people disagree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Relation with Fourier transforms

The `convolve` function in R is using a Fourier transform to compute the convolution (that's a potential source for the difference, although I am not sure, and do not know the details).

$$ x * y = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}\{x\} \cdot \mathcal{F}\{y\}\}$$

But more specifically it is using the complex conjugate, and that is how the operation turns the variable backwards.

```
x = c(c(1,2,3,4),rep(0,4))
y = c(c(5,6,7,8),rep(0,4))
zx = fft(c(x))
zy = fft(c(y)) 
round(Re(fft(zx*Conj(zy), inverse = TRUE))/8)
round(Re(fft(zx*zy, inverse = TRUE))/8)
```

Which returns

```
[1] 70 56 39 20  0  8 23 44
[1]  5 16 34 60 61 52 32  0
```

I am not sure why the conjugate is used. This operation with the conjugate relates to convolution according to

$$\mathcal{F}\{x(t) * y^*(-t)\} = \mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}\cdot\left(\mathcal{F}\{y(t)\}\right)^*$$

and if $y$ is real then $y = y^*$. And it also relates a bit to cross-correlation. In which case

$$\mathcal{F}\{x(t) * y(-t)\} = \mathcal{F}\{x(t)\}\cdot \left(\mathcal{F}\{y(t)\}\right)^*$$

Note that R's `convolve` function is regulating this with a parameter `conj` which is true by default and setting it to false gives the 'normal' convolution.

```
convolve(x,y,conj=FALSE)
```

Indirectly the question could be seen as: "why does R `convolve` use `conj = TRUE` as the default option?"

#### Potential (historic) reason for the difference

Why the standard R function for convolution does it in a reverse way, or how this historically came to be, I do not know. But possibly the origin might stem from the book *Time Series: Data Analysis and Theory* by David R. Brillinger (1981), which is referenced in the R documentation. In the book the convolution occurs as following:

> Suppose the values $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$, $t=0,\dots,T-1$, are available. We will sometimes require the convolution $$\sum_{0\leq {{t}\atop{t+u}} \leq T-1} X(t+u)Y(t) \quad u = 0, \pm 1, \dots \quad (3.6.1)$$

The term convolution is used in a more general sense, and later in the text they refer to a specific case of this type of convolution

> One case in which one might require the convolution (3.6.1) is in the estimation of the moment function $m_{12}(u) = E[X_1(t+u)X_2(t)]$...

Also in early descriptions of the use of the fast Fourier transform algorithm (a reference occuring in Brillinger) do they use 'convolution' in a broader sense. In [Fast Fourier Transforms: for fun and profit](https://doi.org/10.1145/1464291.1464352) AFIPS '66 (Fall): Proceedings of the November 7-10, 1966, fall joint computer conference, Gentleman and Sande write

> ... To date, the most important uses of the fast Fourier transform have been in connection with the convolution theorem of Table I. Some uses of numerical convolutions are the following:
>
> *Auto- and Cross-Covariances:*...
>
> ...
>
> ...The first major use of the convolution theorem, by Sande, was to compute the auto-covariance...

So it seems that, at least in some circles, convolution has a more general meaning and possibly the writers of the R function found the [cross covariance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance#Cross-covariance_of_deterministic_signals) most useful to be the standard (it is mentioned to be a major use).

---

#### Differences in conventions also (already) occurs for Fourier transformation

As whuber noted in the comments, Fourier transformation, from which convolution can be derived, is not uniquely defined. There are several conventions for $a$ and $b$ in the below defined Fourier transformation and reverse Fourier transformation formulae:

$$\begin{array}{}
\mathcal{F}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2\pi)^{1-a}}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{ibxt} \text{d}t \\
f(t) = \sqrt{\frac{|b|}{(2\pi)^{1+a}}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}(x) e^{-ibxt} \text{d}x
\end{array}$$

and different fields use different parameters $a$ and $b$. The scaling parameter $a$ does not relate much to the 'convolution' operation, but the direction/sign of $b$ may be seen as related.

Personally I am still wondering whether this relationship with Fourier transforms (and its ambiguous conventions) is the reason why the R function is different.

We can use Fourier transforms to compute a convolution, but should that be the reason for the diversity in conventions of convolutions?

(note: In the case of Fourier transforms it may be *useful* to have different conventions, depending on the field. Because transforms of particular functions, that are more/less relevant depending on the field, might have some simple form or not depending on the convention.)

Comment: The use of "the" Fourier transform masks the fact that there is no universal convention for Fourier transforms--and this is a big part of the reason why software implementations of the FFT and its related operations, especially convolution, differ.  See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransform.html.

Comment: I agree, writing '*the* Fourier transform' was sloppy. I've corrected this now. Do you believe that ambiguity in parameters in the Fourier transform is reason for the ambiguity in the direction of convolution (because convolution can be seen as derived from FT)? Historically convolution predates the Fourier transform and deriving convolution by means of FT is only an afterthought to make the computations faster. It's probably how it got into the R function, and why I posted this answer, but to me it does not make much sense yet. It is the first time that I see convolution done in this way.

Comment: The absence of a convention for the FT is only one part of it.  I suspect the ambiguity arises for the usual reasons: different communities have different uses for convolution and different conventions and so the software will differ depending on its target audience.

Comment: All this business about the FT is beside the point; convolution and related operations are defined apart from FT, and any relation between them is a consequence to be derived. The relevant part of this answer is the definition from a book about time series which has a definition of convolution which would be called correlation in every other book I've ever seen. The only way to answer OP's question is to go back and find out why convolution was implemented that way in S or S+ from which R got it.

Comment: @RobertDodier the path to the reasoning for convolution in R being different passes by the use of the FFT algorithm. That is where it's use of cross correlation in place of convolution may stem from (and at least, something interesting as a sidenote is to know that, under the hood, in the code, there is no explicit reversal of the variable but it is done indirectly in the frequency domain where it is the conjugation that switches the convolution into cross correlation). The articles describing FFT as a way to perform convolution discussed convolution in a broader sense.